# foreign key implementation may be not correct...insert value in judgedetail then another courttype also save which is not present in court table...

Tags: sqlite

private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "judge";

// Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS_COURT = "courtdetail";

// Court Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID1 = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME1 = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL1 = "email";

```
// judge Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String KEY_COURTTYPE_ID = "courttypeid";
private final ArrayList<JudgeContact> judge_list = new ArrayList<JudgeContact>();
private final ArrayList<Court> contact_list = new ArrayList<Court>();

public JudgeDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables (----KEY_COURTTYPE_ID is foreign key----) 
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " 
    + TABLE_CONTACTS 
    + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," 
    + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_COURTTYPE_ID + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
    + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_COURTTYPE_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_CONTACTS_COURT+" ("+KEY_ID1+")";


String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS_COURT + "("
        + KEY_ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME1 + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_EMAIL1 + " TEXT" + ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE1);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call [setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled%28boolean%29).

Comment: How To call and where is this put..can you briefly explain...thanks in advance

Comment: Is there anything you do not understand about the documentation I linked to?

Comment: i did use  this method after oncreate method bt i get a error ): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed                                           @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            // Enable foreign key constraints
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
    }

Comment: Now you get the error you *want to get*, according to your original question.

Comment: thanx dis problem hv solved...i have another question ........Actually i have 2 screns one is registartion nd 2nd is login i want to set first time registration screen visible by user when registration process is complete den after that only login screen is visible...in one mainactivity both layout want to set suppose no user intially only 1st screen visible if user registered only 2nd screen visible......only one user registered...how will do??  plz suggest me

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.